# What is the meaning of "quixotic stance"?

Tags: meaning, literature

> *quixotic stance*

I guess it refers to a kind of standing position. It may have something to do with chivalry and Don Quixote as well.
The context it is used in, is somebody tantalizing someone else.
What kind of a stance is it?

Answer (score 1):

"Quixotic" is rarely used literally to refer to Don Quixote specifically these days; without additional context, I would understand this to mean that whoever is the subject of this phrase has a quixotic attitude (aka *stance)* to something.

Merriam-Webster [defines *quixotic*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quixotic) as

> 1. foolishly impractical especially in the pursuit of ideals
>    *especially:* marked by rash lofty romantic ideas or extravagantly chivalrous action
> 2. CAPRICIOUS, UNPREDICTABLE

Not very tantalizing, if you ask me, unless you are Dulcinea.

Comment: ...and _stance_ could refer to the (mental) attitude someone is taking, rather than a physical position.

Comment: Question is seriously lacking in context.